# C preprocessor Concatenation in a for loop

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to use concatenation in a for loop? My code snippet is like this:

```
#define CONCATE(a, b) a ## b
#define CALL_SEARCH(n, x, y) search(n, arg1, arg2, x, y)
...
int i;
for (i = 1; i (less than or equal to) number; ++i)
{
    results = CALL_SEARCH(CONCATE(f, i), tol, max_tries);
}
```

What I want to do in this for loop is like this:

search(f1, arg1, arg2, tol, max_tries)

search(f2, arg1, arg2, tol, max_tries)

...

I know my version is obviously wrong but that's the result I want to archive.

**EDIT:**

I decided not to use macro for this.

Comment: Why don't you just use an array `f`?

Comment: Go look at [`Boost::Preprocessor`](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor) which is actually portable to C too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCATENATE` creates "`fi`", not "`f1`". You want `f` to be an array and use `i` as an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing is only text replacement which is done before compiling. At this stage, we therefore don't know the value of `int i`.

If you wish to concatenate the text string "f" and the value of i at runtime, you may do this:

```
char buf[10];
snprintf(buf, 10, "f%i", i);
```

and then

```
CALL_SEARCH(buf, ...)
```